# Excel Remove Duplicates Cells with different Strings Order

Tags: excel, vba

How to remove duplicates cells with different data ordering

| A header |
| --- |
| it is amazing day |
| it is amazing |
| amazing day |
| amazing day it is |

Expected Result

| A header |
| --- |
| it is amazing day |
| it is amazing |
| amazing day |

Note That my Cells Strings could be up to 7

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. You have tagged this with Excel-Formula but your goal of cell removal suggests a VBA solution. Do you want to remove cells or just filter them?

Comment: @bugdrown 1. couldn't try because it need a VBA module which i don't having experience within 2. yeah remove them + i edited tags

Comment: Have you researched any VBA possibilities on the web? You could post the results of your efforts if they don't quite meet your need. Can you clarify if you're trying to delete each row that is listed as Duplicated? Or if you want to keep one of the rows and delete just the duplicates of that row?

Comment: I searched on MrExcel forum didn't find anything similar or maybe my poor english is the issue, Keep First One and remove other duplicates

Comment: How is the Another Header column populated? What's the formula?

Comment: So you consider a sentence as duplicate if any permutation by taking each word appear twice?

Comment: until u said permutation my answer is yes , about by taking each word appear twice i don't understand this part, i edit the example i hope it be more clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string into words, sort them to create a key and use a dictionary to find duplicates.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ar, s As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    Dim dict As Object, key As String, rng As Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
    Set ws = Sheet1
    With ws
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 2 To lastrow
            
            ' split and sort words into key
            s = Application.Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
            ar = bubblesort(Split(s, " "))
            key = Join(ar, " ")
            
            ' check dupicate
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                .Cells(i, "B") = "Duplicated"
                If n = 0 Then
                    Set rng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set rng = Application.Union(rng, .Rows(i))
                End If
                n = n + 1
            Else
                .Cells(i, "B") = "Unique"
                dict.Add key, i
            End If
            
       Next
    End With
       
    ' delete duplicates
    If n > 0 Then
        If MsgBox(n & " duplicates found, do you want to delete them ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            rng.Delete
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No duplicates found", vbInformation
    End If
   
End Sub

Function bubblesort(ar)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, tmp As String
    For a = 0 To UBound(ar)
         For b = a + 1 To UBound(ar)
             If CStr(ar(a)) > CStr(ar(b)) Then
                 tmp = ar(a)
                 ar(a) = ar(b)
                 ar(b) = tmp
             End If
         Next
     Next
     bubblesort = ar
End Function
```

Comment: My bad i am sry that u thought there was there a column have values duplicated and values, I edited the post
there are only one column

Comment: @shikez this answer should still meet your needs as it only assumes text is in Column A. It populates Column B with "Duplicated"/"Unique" but it never uses that data so you could just as easily remove those assignments. The code will build a dictionary of values as it goes (each with its words sorted): `{"amazing day is it", "amazing is it", "amazing day"}`. When it reaches the last one it will sort the words to `"amazing day is it"` which is already in the dictionary so that 4th data row will be marked for deletion. At the end of the code all rows marked for deletion are deleted.

Comment: Yeah it worked Thanks aloooot, my bad i though it taking data from column two and tried it in Sheet2 so it didn't work Thanks bro